# How can I check if an specific field exists in my database and add the record if it doesn't and edit it otherwise

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

This is my code in my registration form:

```
    public override void Guardar()
    {
        if (ValidarCampos() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Desea guardar este registro?", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
                    {
                        bool contactExists = db.cliente.Any(o => o.nombre_cliente.Equals(txtRegCliente.Text));
                        if (contactExists)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("El cliente ingresado ya existe");
                            txtRegCliente.Clear();
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        if (cliente_id == null)
                                oCliente = new cliente();

                            oCliente.nombre_cliente = txtRegCliente.Text;
                            oCliente.vendedor_id = Convert.ToInt32(cbRegVendedor.SelectedValue);
                            oCliente.tipo_cliente_id = Convert.ToInt32(cbRegTipoCliente.SelectedValue);

                            if (cliente_id == null)
                            {
                                db.cliente.Add(oCliente);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                db.Entry(oCliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            }
                        db.SaveChanges();
                            MessageBox.Show("Se ha guardado correctamente");
                            this.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error: " + error.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have 2 buttons, New and Edit, both open the same windows form. If I click "New" the textbox and combobox are clean and if it's "Edit" the form will be open with the values from database. It works fine when it's "New" but when it's "Edit" and I want to modify another textbox that is not "nombre_cliente" I get a message: "The customer already exist". I just want to return to the form if the especific textbox "nombre_cliente" is already in the database in both cases "New" and "Edit" I am using windows form, EF Database, C#

EDIT:

This is my first form:

[image]

And it's code(the important part for my problem) :

```
    private int? GetId()
    {
        try
        {
            return int.Parse(dgvTablas.Rows[dgvTablas.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public override void Nuevo()
    {
        Presentation.FrmRegCliente oCliente = new Presentation.FrmRegCliente();
        oCliente.ShowDialog();

        Refrescar();
    }

    public override void Editar()
    {
        int? cliente_id = GetId();
        if (cliente_id != null)
        {
            Presentation.FrmRegCliente oCliente = new Presentation.FrmRegCliente(cliente_id);
            oCliente.ShowDialog();

            Refrescar();
        }
    }
```

And my second form for add or edit a record:

[image]

And the part of code that I skipped at the beginning:

```
public partial class FrmRegCliente : FrmBaseGuardar
{
    public int? cliente_id;
    cliente oCliente = null;
    public FrmRegCliente(int? cliente_id = null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.cliente_id = cliente_id;
        if (cliente_id != null)
            CargaDatos();
        else
        {
            CargarVendedor();
            CargarTipoCliente();
        }
    }


    private void CargaDatos()
    {
        CargarVendedor();
        CargarTipoCliente();


        using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
        {

            oCliente = db.cliente.Find(cliente_id);
            cliente_id = oCliente.cliente_id;
            txtRegCliente.Text = oCliente.nombre_cliente;
            cbRegVendedor.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(oCliente.vendedor_id);
            cbRegTipoCliente.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(oCliente.tipo_cliente_id);
        }

    }
```

//button "Guardar" code
PD: Sorry if my grammar is incorrect, english is not my first language

Comment: Seems to me that you have a design problem here if you don't know how to tell in your application if this is an update or an insert. What is cliente_id? That seems to be defined outside this method. Something seems off in your code here but I can't quite place what it is.

Comment: Sean Lange I catch cliente_id from another form, when I click in a row i get the id of the record. Can you check again what could be my specific problem? I have updated my question with more code.

Comment: In your call to save (Guardar) you are checking if the record exists with the `contactExists` variable, which it does as it's an edit call. And then you show the message if `contactExists` is true, which it is. Why are you showing the message if you don't want it?

Comment: @quaabaam I want the message just if the specific field (nombre_cliente) already exists in my database, otherwise I want to save the record either it's a new one or just modified some other fields. Happens that when I want to edit another field that is not nombre_cliente my first try show me the message that nombre_ cliente already exists and its true but I just want to edit another field in that record.